# Non-trivial extension and tangent bundle isotropic Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians

Let $V$ be a $2n$-dimensional vector space endowed with a nondegenerate skew-symmetric form $q:V \to V^\vee$. We define the isotropic Grassmannian to be
$$
X:=G_q(k,V)=\left\{[W] \in \mathbb P \left( \bigwedge^k V\right): W \subset V \text{ and } W \text{ is }q-\text{isotropic}\right\}.
$$
We denote the rank $k$ tautological bundle over $X$ by $\mathcal S \hookrightarrow V \otimes \mathcal O_X$. The cokernel will be denoted by $\mathcal Q$.
Thanks to the quadratic form, we also have the inclusion $\mathcal S \hookrightarrow \mathcal Q^\vee$ and we denote $\mathcal K$ to be the cokernel $\mathcal Q^\vee/\mathcal S$.

One can prove that the tangent bundle $T_X$ fits in the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal S^\vee \otimes \mathcal K \longrightarrow T_X \longrightarrow S^2 \mathcal S^\vee \to 0.
$$
**Question.**
Is it true that $T_X$ is the unique non-trivial extension for the short exact sequence? How can we prove it?

I tried to compute $H^1\left(X,S^2\mathcal S \otimes\mathcal S^\vee \otimes \mathcal K\right)$ without significant results.

Comment: How did you try to compute $H^1$?

Comment: I tensor the short exact sequence by $\operatorname{Hom}(S^2 \mathcal S^\vee,\cdot)$ and then induce the long exact sequence in cohomology.  Since $S^2 \mathcal S^\vee$ is globally generated, its dual is not. Hence $H^0(X, \operatorname{Hom}(S^2\mathcal S^\vee,S^2 \mathcal S^\vee))$ is zero. So I can conclude that
$$
H^1(X,\operatorname{Hom}(S^2\mathcal S^\vee,\mathcal S^\vee \otimes \mathcal K)) \hookrightarrow H^1(X,\operatorname{Hom}(S^2\mathcal S^\vee,T_X)).
$$
But I cannot say something more for the moment being

Comment: Why don't you apply Borel--Bott--Weil instead?

Comment: Because I don't know who are the representations associated with the vector bundles appearing in the sequence

Comment: Do you know how the equivalence between equivariant bundles on a homogeneous variety and representations of the stabilizer of a point works?